# Having a little issue understanding the code

Tags: java, arrays, string, sorting, int

I have quite unusual request and i hope i can ask you for professional feedback. I have a little problem understanding following piece of code.

Code:

```
Class TestTablic {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
      int [] indeks = new int[4];  
      indeks[0] = 1;
      indeks[1] = 3;
      indeks[2] = 0;
      indeks[3] = 2;
      String[] islands = new String[4];  
      Islands[0] = "Bermudy";
      Islands[1] = "Fiji";
      Islands[2] = "Azory";
      Islands[3] = "Kozumel";
      int y = 0;
      int ref;
      while (y < 4) {
        ref = indeks[y];
        System.out.print("Island = ");
        System.out.println(Islands[ref]);
        y = y + 1;
  }
 }
}
```

I'd appreciate someone who could break it down step by step to me to see if i understood it correctly!

(I'm mostly puzzled about the `int ref` part, is it even neccessary? I took the following code from the book i use to learn java but they put a lot of confusing lines in there...)

Cheers!

Comment: `int ref` declares a variable called `ref` being of the primitive integer datatype.  Without it, subsequent references to that variable would result in compiler errors.

Comment: java is case sensitive. islands and Islands not same. so there will be a compilation error

Comment: Or delete the line and add "int " before the ref in the loop to have a local declaration. It is not used outside the loop anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ref` is defined in the body of the loop as corresponding to `ref = indeks[y];`. Given the previous definition of `indeks` [1, 3, 0, 2] it will output the `islands` (note lower case "i")

```
Fiji
Kozumel
Bermudy
Azory
```

So, bringing it all together

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] indeks = new int[4];
    indeks[0] = 1;
    indeks[1] = 3;
    indeks[2] = 0;
    indeks[3] = 2;
    String[] islands = new String[4];
    islands[0] = "Bermudy";
    islands[1] = "Fiji";
    islands[2] = "Azory";
    islands[3] = "Kozumel";
    int y = 0;
    int ref;
    while (y < 4) {
        ref = indeks[y];
        System.out.print("Island = ");
        System.out.println(islands[ref]);
        y = y + 1;
    }
}
```

Which outputs (when I run it) -

```
Island = Fiji
Island = Kozumel
Island = Bermudy
Island = Azory
```

Comment: Thanks a lot of your answer. One more question (I hope i understood it correctly) Wouldn't be easier if i refered to the "islands" string directly without declaring another integer (the ref one) specifically for that?

Comment: @Lotix: yes, it would be easier (and a lot more understandable) – for example you could get the islands by calling `System.out.println(islands[y]);` (as in using the y index directly to access the islands array) – however that would result in a different order.

Comment: @Lotix Or, you could use the [for-each](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html) loop.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That's exactly what i was wondering about :) Much appreciated.